# Can I create a new APNS production certificate without affecting older one which is being used in live app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I don't have private key of APNS certificate which is being used in live app where notifications are working fine. However, I want to integrate freshchat sdk which requires APNS certificate to be uploaded on their server. Is it possible to create a new APNS certificate for this whithout affecting the previos one? SO basically I'll have two APNS certificate(prodcution) for one bundleID

Comment: Create a new certificate and replace it for existing one too(On server/backend). It will not create any issue for the existing app, which will work as it is and you will have the same certificate for new SDK too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have up to two certificates each for sandbox and production:

[image]

Assuming you only have one certificate now, you could add a second.

This time, though, back up that private key!

Both certificates can be used at the same time. You could, for example, transition your existing services to use the new certificate. Once they have all been updated you could remove the old certificate for which you have no private key.